# Spring Reactor and server sent events connection problems

Tags: java, spring-boot, project-reactor, server-sent-events

I have a web application that uses spring reactor "webflux" and server sent events to push notifications.
Sometimes and "*I can't be precise about it*" the server stops sending events after establishing the http connection. The connection remains opened without any errors on the client side. And with no errors thrown on the server side also.
How should I approach this problem. Is their any tools I can use that helps me identify the issue?
I'm new to those technologies so please forgive me if my explanation is not professional.

Comment: Did you try turning up logging to debug/trace levels?

Comment: Sorry, but this is way too broad at the moment - it's essentially unanswerable. I'd recommend turning on all the debugging you can, and trying all the corner cases you can to see if you can narrow down a scenario where it happens reliably, then work out a [mcve] from that.

Answer (score 0):

I've turned on all the debugging, adding logs in doOnCancel, doFinally, doOnerror and doOnComplete. Printed stack trances. but could not obtain any errors, or any unexpected behavior from the fluxes.
At the end I've decided to switch to Jetty instead of tomcat as an embedded server. and everything started to work like a charm.